# Convert char * to string literal

Tags: c++, pragma, string-literals

I want to use a char * with #pragma message to tell where my problems are in the Visual Studio debugger.

```
void OutputShaderErrors(const char *filename)
{
  std::string outputMessage = "Errors written to: ";
  outputMessage += filename;

  #pragma message(outputMessage.c_str())
}
```

The above block of code does work, but the following warning is given:

```
Warning 1   warning C4083: expected 'string'; found identifier 'outputMessage'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `#` in `#pragma` suggest, this is a feature of the preprocessor. You cannot *call* it at runtime. The code does not actually work, and the warning you see comes from your invalid use of `#pragma`.

Since you are working with *Visual Studio*, you may find the `OutputDebugMessage` function useful.

Comment: Wow, so this is impossible?  Bummer.

Comment: @btcode: Since you are working with _Visual Studio_, you may find the `OutputDebugMessage` function useful...